# Meaning of "They shared the blame for old Hannah’s miserable silence"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, literature

> But Lucy knew it would be. It was for ever for the Morells and the
> Gouvernets. The Boyces had gone up to the North, Henry said, the house
> was under auction. She guessed what that meant from his voice, but he
> told her anyway.
> "I’m sorry," her papa said. "I’m sorry, Lucy."

> It was her mother’s fault, but it was his fault too. **They shared the blame for old Hannah’s miserable silence** and Kitty Teresa’s eyes gone red and her apron soaking with the tears that streamed on her cheeks and her neck, causing Bridget twenty times a day to tell her to give over. Henry slouchedglumly about the yard.

Is "Share **for**" the same as "Share **with**"
?

And does the whole part in bold mean: they talk to old Hanna that was miserably silence and blamed themselvs?

Source: The Story Of Lucy Gault By William Trevor

Comment: The mother and father shared the blame (were both to blame) for Hannah's silence and Kitty Teresa's weeping.

Comment: So does it mean: they blamed old Hanna for being silent?

Comment: No, they _were to blame_ for it - something they had done had caused it.

Comment: So Dose it mean: because of their fault old Hanna was silent and they blamed themselves?

Comment: Either they blamed themselves or someone else blamed them both.

Comment: can we say they blamed themselves for Kitty Teresa's weeping too? or Kitty Teresa was weeping because they blamed themselves for Old Hanna's silent?

Comment: The quoted passage does not make clear whether Henry blamed himself or not, but it is clear that he felt bad in some way.

Comment: _Read what I said in my first comment!_ Yes, the blame was for both things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"They shared the blame for old Hannah’s miserable silence  means that Henry and Lucy's mother were both to blame **for** "Hannah’s miserable silence" and  Kitty Teresa’s crying. That is, they were responsible for these things, had caused them.

This passage seems to be from Lucy's point-of-view, but is told in third person. So it might be that it is Lucy's opinion that the two of them are both to blame, or it might be the narrator's view. (Or perhaps both.) In fiction, the narrator's view of things is generally taken to be the truth, although that varies.

Comment: In this text it is saying that: Kitty Teresa 's eyes gone red and...it is not saying: Kitty Teresa' weeping. So I think Kitty Teresa broke to tears because they talked to themselves and thought it is their fault that old Hanna is silent. Am I right?

Comment: In this context 'for' refer to 'blame' or means: because?

Comment: @Viser "Kitty Teresa’s eyes gone red and her apron soaking with the tears that streamed on her cheeks" means that she (Kitty) has been crying tears. Her eyes were red as a result of this crying. The quoted passage says Lucy's father and mother are to blame for this redness and tears. It says nothing about people talking to themselves or blaming themselves. Nor does it say exactly how they were to blame for Kitty's tears. Perhaps other passages make this clear, I haven't read the work.

Comment: @Viser When someone is "to blame for" something, it means that that person caused that thing, or is responsible for it. "to be to blame for" is a phrasal verb meaning "to cause" with a negative implication. "the blame for" something is a noun phrase The blame is an attribute associated with the event that the person blamed has caused or for which that person is responsible.